# Loop through equal_range in a boost::unordered_multimap

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-multimap

I am trying to learn how to iterate through the values returned from a boost::unordered_multimap which have the same keys. So, I did this,

`boost::unordered_multimap<string, string> sample;`

In which I have maybe,

```
<"one", "1">,

<"one", "11">,

<"two", "2">,

<"three", "3">,

<"three", "3">,

<"three", "33">,

<"three", "333">,
```

and I try to get the values corresponding to "two" so I did this,

```
std::pair<boost::unordered_multimap<string, string>::iterator, boost::unordered_multimap<string, string>::iterator> > ret = sample.equal_range("two");
```

and I iterate through it like,

```
for(boost::unordered_multimap<string, string>::iterator> it = ret.first ; it != ret.second; it++)
{
    cout<<"The values mapped are : "<<*it->second<<"\n";
}
```

Would I get the value : 2, since that is the only value that is mapped? Would I get out of the loop the first time? I am trying to get the answer online/on boost documentation, but I havent succeeded. It might be a basic question but I am trying to learn. Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

-R

Answer (score 1):

About **boost: equal_range(key& vkey):**

**Usage:**

```
std::pair<iterator, iterator> Equal_Range = Unordered_Map.equal_range("key");
```

**Return:**

A map table contains all the mapped result by **KEY:** `key`. `Equal_Range.first` represents the first location in the result table, while `Equal_Range.second` represents the last. **Special case:** If ONLY one element matched, `ret.first` point to the location mapped by `key`, and `ret.second` point to the last location on original map: which is `original_map.last`.

So by using `equal_range(key& vkey)`, you already get the result table `std::pair<itr1, itr2>`, which stores all the mapped results you found, and `itr1` is the first location mapped by `vkey` while `itr2` represents the last. So your code works fine:

```
for(auto Itr = ret.first; Itr != ret.second; ++Itr)
        std::cout << "The values mapped are : " << Itr->second << std::endl;
```

**Test case:** `key` = `"three"`

```
The values mapped are : 3
The values mapped are : 3
The values mapped are : 33
The values mapped are : 333
```

Comment: I am not sure that I have only one value mapped, I might have had two, three or n values mapped. So a loop would be my choice. I wanted to know if after calling an equal_range and iterating through the return pair, if I would get all the values mapped to it INCLUDING THE LAST ONE..

Comment: Check my **EDIT**.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. I tried it and it works. I understand, but I would like to understand how this works if only ONE value is mapped to the key element. The ret returned from the equal_range call would be like ret.first would be equal to the ret.last and so that loop should not be entered at all right? How does this work, that is my confusion.

Comment: Oh, ok. But if ret.first is the location mapped by the key and ret.second points to the first location on sample(which would be <"one", "1">) right how would that work? Did you mean ret.second would point to the location just before the first(and only occurance) of the key? Also if that is the case, unordered_map is not arranged in any specific fashion right? How would that work?

Comment: My mistake, if ONLY one  matched, ret.second point to the last element in sample.

Comment: Also, `unordered_map` is arranged in a way like a **reverse** vector of `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<key, value>>>`.